# Openshift origin multiple master changing configuration

Tags: configuration, openshift, identity, openshift-origin

I have 3 masters in my Openshift cluster. After changing identity provider in `master-config.yaml` and restarting `master-api` and `master-controller` in one, it doesn't take any effect unless I copy this configuration to all masters in the cluster. I'm wondering why?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is affected by master service [HA architecture](https://docs.okd.io/3.9/architecture/infrastructure_components/kubernetes_infrastructure.html#high-availability-masters) and they have each configuration so it needs to sync if they are changed. For example, the controller service access to a elected leader at a time. And as I remember, this architecture is changed as of v3.10, the configuration file managed as one configmap which shared with same node group,  so node would not require to restart to take effec, but master service should needs to restart each master services if the configuration changed.